# Get first day/date of previous month and last day/date of next month

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, time, nsdate

I want to get the first day and date of the previous month, and the last day and date of the next month.
For example, the current month is April. I want 1st March and 31st May.

How do I get this info from `NSDate`?

Although there are solutions to get first day of current month, I think it won't help me to get first day of previous month and last day of next month.

I have already tried:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:( NSYearCalendarUnit |
NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

But here [NSDate date] is current date, but I want prev and next dates.

Comment: I want to get first day of last / previous month, and not first day of current month

Comment: Read the solution there and then try something out. There's only one step to add.

Comment: Look at NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents and related operations.